# Need input with adding second MySql Update in conditional IF

Tags: php, mysql

just trying to add a second Update inside the second if (if $amount == "0.00"

It all works perfectly, until I try to add this bit in below:

Bit to add:

```
$updateSQL = "UPDATE brick_codes 
              SET number_of_uses= '$number_of_uses' 
              WHERE code= 'bricks_type_0005'";
```

My code:

```
if ($amount != "0.00")  :
$updateSQL = "UPDATE bricks 
              SET payment_page_completed = '$payment_page_completed'
                , discount = '$discount'
                , discount_code_used = '$discount_code_used'
                , access_period = '$access_period'
                , gift_certificate = '$gift_certificate'
                , bricks_price = '$bricks_price' 
              WHERE brick_id = '$brick_id'";

elseif( $amount == "0.00" ) : 

$updateSQL = "UPDATE bricks 
              SET payment_page_completed = '$payment_page_completed'
                , discount='$discount'
                , discount_code_used='$discount_code_used'
                , access_period='$access_period'
                , gift_certificate='$gift_certificate'
                , bricks_price='$bricks_price'
                , payment_date='$payment_date'
                , bricks_paid='$bricks_paid'";
```

// THIS BIT TRYING TO ADD BUT NOW WORKING

```
 $updateSQL = "UPDATE brick_codes 
               SET number_of_uses = '$number_of_uses' 
               WHERE code = 'bricks_type_0005'";
```

// END NEW BIT

```
 WHERE bricks_id = '$bricks_id'"; 
 endif;
```

Ideas? Been looking at it toooo long..

Comment: remove the quotes from '$number_of_uses', if it's an INT value.

Comment: Can you paste the entire script?

Comment: +1. Question - are you how are you executing the queries in 
$updateSQL?  Are you trying to put them in the same statement, or are you calling the database twice?  Exactly what is the result  you are getting?

Comment: Not much more to the script.. define $number_of_uses etc but that's it.. everything working fine, except when try to add second update...

Comment: When I have bot the updates in nothing is updating at all..

Comment: Want to be two seperate updates really.. not dependent on each other..

Answer (score 0):

If you use this syntax:

```
if ($var = something) :
```

You can also execute one statement after the `if`.  I would advice you to **never** use this syntax and use brackets `{ ... }` instead, whatever you place inside the brackets is executed, be it 1 or 100 statements.

You code will look something like this:

```
if ($amount != "0.00") {
  $updateSQL1 = "UPDATE bricks 
          SET payment_page_completed = '$payment_page_completed'
            , discount = '$discount'
            , discount_code_used = '$discount_code_used'
            , access_period = '$access_period'
            , gift_certificate = '$gift_certificate'
            , bricks_price = '$bricks_price' 
          WHERE brick_id = '$brick_id'";
  $updateSQL2 = //insert second UPDATE statement here.
} else { //no need for an explicit test, just use an else.
  $updateSQL1 = //insert update statement here.
  $updateSQL2 = "SELECT 1"; //empty statement, or another UPDATE, whatever you want.
}
```

The indentation makes the structure of the program clear, every time you have an opening `{` you indent with 2 spaces, every time you have a closing `}` you unindent two spaces.

Always use the brackets, even if you have only a single statement inside them, because that way you cannot get errors if you want to add another statement later.

Comment: seems like the error msg has something to do with $updateSQL1 and $updateSQL2????

Comment: If I take away 1 and 2.. then no longer get error message... but nothing updates.. :(

Comment: @user718359, Please don't be silly, you need to execute both queries, one after another `mysql_query($updateSQL1); mysql_query($updateSQL2);`

Comment: Sorry I meant if I just rename $updateSQL1 and $updateSQL2 to $updateSQL and $updateSQL

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3948/discussion-between-user718359-and-johan)

Answer (score -1):

you need to format your if statements better!

```
if ($amount != "0.00")
{

    $updateSQL = "UPDATE bricks SET payment_page_completed='$payment_page_completed',discount='$discount',discount_code_used='$discount_code_used', access_period='$access_period', gift_certificate='$gift_certificate',bricks_price='$bricks_price' WHERE brick_id='$brick_id'";
}
elseif( $amount == "0.00" )
{

    $updateSQL = "UPDATE bricks SET payment_page_completed='$payment_page_completed',discount='$discount', discount_code_used='$discount_code_used',access_period='$access_period', gift_certificate='$gift_certificate',bricks_price='$bricks_price', payment_date='$payment_date', bricks_paid='$bricks_paid'";

    // Execute this one...

    $updateSQL = "UPDATE brick_codes SET number_of_uses='$number_of_uses' WHERE   code='bricks_type_0005'";

    // Then execute this one...

}
```

Comment: I think if are ok, he's using the other syntax (if(): endif;) You're overwritting the $updateSQL variable.

Comment: Sorry - did iot solve it was regarding the formatting not the comment by santiagobasulto

Comment: When I put in the second update (the one I am trying to add) nothing is updating from the second if at all???

Comment: erm... you have 2 update statements - you would need to execute one and then the other...

Comment: Yep, I thought that to and just repeated the entire IF leaveing the first one blank and just including the second update in the second if.. but was not working??

Comment: I did this.. if ($amount != "0.00")  : ;